# Multer doesn't display

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I am using multer, MongoDB, and expressjs but the problem is about multer. Because I can upload my images to my `public/uploads/` folder but I cannot show it in my webpage.

Here when I do `console.log(article.img)`, I get `public\uploads\image.png`:

Then this is the part of my `route.js`:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public/uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname)
  }
})
const upload = multer({storage: storage})

[...]

router.post('/add',upload.single('img'),  function(req, res){
var article = new Article({
    title: req.body.title,
    author: req.user._id,
    img: req.file.path,
    body: req.body.body,
   });
```

This is my coded to get single article:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res){
  Article.findById(req.params.id, function(err, article){
    //User.findById(article.author, function(err, user){
      res.render('article', {
        article:article,
        //imagePath: article.img,
        //author: user.name
      });
    });
  });
```

This is my relevant `add_article.pug` page:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 #{title}
  form(method='POST',  enctype = "multipart/form-data", action='/articles/add')
    #form-group
      label Title:
      input.form-control(name='title', type='text')
      #form-group
      label Author:
      input.form-control(name='author', type='text')
    #form-group
      label Body:
      textarea.form-control(name='body')
    .file-field.input-field(method="post")
      .btn.grey
        label File
        input(name='img', type='file', enctype="multipart/form-data")
    br
    input.btn.btn-primary(type='submit',value='Submit')
```

**Also this is my `article.pug`:

```
extends layout

block content
  br
  //h5 Written by #{author}
  h1= article.title
  p= article.body
  img.img-responsive(src=article.img, alt=article.img)
```

There are some articles that you upload and you can write title, author, body, and add an image to that article. Just like it happens in medium or in webwhatsapp.

This is my file information:

```
{ fieldname: 'img',
  originalname: 'image.png',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/png',
  destination: 'public/uploads',
  filename: 'image.png',
  path: 'public\\uploads\\ateş ulsuu.png',
  size: 4084 } [Object: null prototype] {
  title: 'ZAİB SİTESİ DENEME',
  author: 'ALP EREN GÜL',
  body: 'asdasdsad' }
```

As you can see I have title, author, and body also I have image. But I cannot understand why I cannot implement it to my webpage.

Comment: Please help me. For a long time more than 3 Months I am having trouble with this issue.

Comment: You are passing relative path, you need to give absolute path, so `public/upload/img.png` becomes `https://example.com/public/uploads/img.png`. Also you need to give access to public folder  using `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

Comment: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); this is already given in my app.js